# the way I had tried didn't work!Facebook SDK returned an error

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook SDK returned an error: Cross-site request forgery validation failed. The "state" param from the URL and session do not match.

ok.I have try all the way that I find on the stackoverflow about the same question,but unfortunately,the same question has occured all the time,I am crazy now.Please help me!

this is the login.php:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '\Facebook\autoload.php';

if(!session_id()) {
   session_start();
}

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
'app_id' => 'my_app_id',
'app_secret' => 'and_my_app_secret',
'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
// 'persistent_data_handler'=>'session',
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

$permissions = ['email']; // Optional permissions
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://my_ip/facebook/login-callback.php',        $permissions);
foreach ($_SESSION as $k=>$v) {                    
   if(strpos($k, "FBRLH_")!==FALSE) {
       if(!setcookie($k, $v)) {
           echo "there is no cookie";
           exit;
       } else {
           $_COOKIE[$k]=$v;
       }
   }
}
var_dump($_COOKIE);
echo '<a href="' . htmlspecialchars($loginUrl) . '">Log in with Facebook!    </a>';
```

?>

and this is the login-callback.php:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '\Facebook\autoload.php';

if(!session_id()) {
   session_start();
}

foreach ($_COOKIE as $k=>$v) {
    if(strpos($k, "FBRLH_")!==FALSE) {
        $_SESSION[$k]=$v;
    }
}

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
'app_id' => 'my_app_id',
'app_secret' => 'my_app_secret',
'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
// 'persistent_data_handler'=>'session',
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

try {
  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
  var_dump($accessToken);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

if (! isset($accessToken)) {
 if ($helper->getError()) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo "Error: " . $helper->getError() . "\n";
    echo "Error Code: " . $helper->getErrorCode() . "\n";
    echo "Error Reason: " . $helper->getErrorReason() . "\n";
    echo "Error Description: " . $helper->getErrorDescription() . "\n";
 } else {
 header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
 echo 'Bad request';
 }
  exit;
 }

 // Logged in
 echo '<h3>Access Token</h3>';
 var_dump($accessToken->getValue());

 $_SESSION['fb_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

hello correct your permission variable like

```
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( 'app_id','app_secreat' );
 // login helper with redirect_uri
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('redirect url' );
try {
 $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
 } catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
 $session = null;
      // When Facebook returns an error
            } catch( Exception $ex ) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
        }
      // see if we have a session
   if ( isset( $session ) ) {
       // graph api request for user data

    $accessToken = $session->getAccessToken();
  $longLivedAccessToken = $accessToken->extend();
     if (isset($longLivedAccessToken)) {
       // Logged in!
             $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string)            $longLivedAccessToken;
      }

       $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me',
      array(
          'fields' => 'id,name,email'
      ) );

         $response = $request->execute();
     // get response
 $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
        //print_r($graphObject);die();
       $fbid = $graphObject->getProperty('id');              // To Get              Facebook ID
    $fbfullname = $graphObject->getProperty('name'); // To Get Facebook full name
    $femail = $graphObject->getProperty('email'); 

     //checkuser($fbid,$fbfullname,$femail);

        $request1 = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me/accounts',
        array(
        'fields' => 'id,access_token,name'
           ) );

    $pageList= $request1->execute()
      ->getGraphObject()
      ->asArray();
```

use this code and get request

Comment: my code is :$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://my_ip/facebook/login-callback.php', array(
    'scope'=>'email,manage_pages,publish_pages'));

Comment: use FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( 'app_id',app_secreat' );
// login helper with redirect_uri
    $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper(redirect_uri' );

Comment: set your redirect url in also app setting

Comment: my_ip/facebook/login-callback.php<---this url is not the redirect url?

Comment: i know ,tell me what you trying to do only login with facebook.

Comment: such as get my head-img or the lists of my friends,but I think the login progress is necessary.

Comment: yes for this you must get session from redirect url,that generates access token for user and that access token used for graph api request.

Comment: now the error is beoming the "Required param "state" missing".

Comment: i update my answer with code use it according to your use

Comment: which file?the login.php?

Comment: no fbconfig.php(that files contains all your code for getting request with graph api)

Comment: the config.php?I can't find it.I don't understand,is it the name called config.php?or something else?

Comment: its  login-callback.php

Comment: I change the hold code in the file login-callback.php,but it still doesn't work.

Comment: are you place redirect url in app setting page with login-callback.php

Comment: hey,man.thanks.I has worked out my question.It is about my IP.

Answer (score 0):

Please Go to the file

src/Facebook/PersistentData/PersistentDataFactory.php

In Your Facebook SDK

find this Code

```html
if ('session' === $handler) {
             new FacebookSessionPersistentDataHandler();
            
          }
```

and Replace With

```html
if ('session' === $handler) {
             return new FacebookSessionPersistentDataHandler();
          }
```

Comment: I am sorry.My facebook dir has no such file caller PersistentDataFactory.My dir is that:PersistentDataFactory,there are three files below it:FacebookMemoryPersistentDataHandler,FacebookSessionPersistentDataHandler,and PersistentDataInterface.there is no such note in the PersistentDataInterface.Why?is it about the version?

Comment: Make sure you enter the same website URL in the app settings and in the script and once you are done with this then remove the app from your Facebook account settings and then close all tabs and browser then try again.

Comment: at the field call "Client OAuth Settings"?yes,I have added the URL earlier.Do I need to add the full dir instead of my ip only?

Comment: No need to Add Full URL Just URL. Http://example.com

Comment: now the error is beoming the "Required param "state" missing".